# how to Ignore "where clause" if no query is provided with Laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to get all the leads when the query is empty, but if the 'subService' query is provided then it should fetch all the leads that have the same subService name

I am trying to get sub service name by providing this `subService.name` in where clause

`subService` is one many relationship

this is not the full code.

```
return Lead::with(['subService'])    
->where(function ($query) use($subService) {
     if ($subService) {
       $query->where('subService.name','like', '%'.$subService.'%');
     }
 })
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
return Lead::with(['subService'])->when($subservice, function ($query) use ($subservice) {
            return $query->whereHas('subService', function ($query) use ($subservice) {
                $query->where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$subservice}%");
            });
        })->get();
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I have even tried the same thing but was not happening, maybe there was some mistake in my code. thanks for the solution.